# Rename_if column in R with prefix if name %in% list: lists do not match

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a list of tibbles which have been created with `map` functions. The column names are as follows...

```
dfA[[1]]%>% colnames(.)  
[1] "date_strt"  "grouped_id" "10938_0"    "12881_0"
```

The numbered column names create issues for a function I am using (mice), and I need to change them to have a string prefixed to the beginning. As I need to do this for **a large number of tibbles** I cannot reference the names directly. So I have created lists of character vectors from another tibbles `names`

```
df_list <- dfB %>% names() %>% as.vector()
```

Some of the names have the string "ITEM" prefixed, so I remove this for the matching list.

```
df_list <- purrr::map(df_list ,function(x){x %>% str_remove(.,"ITEM")})
```

When I attempt to then append according to the strings, we get some unwanted special characters

```
purrr::map2(dfA, df_list, function(df, name_list)
    df %>% rename_if(colnames(.) %in% name_list, ~paste0("ITEM", .)))

[[1]] date_strt           grouped_id `ITEM\`12881_0\`` `ITEM\`79916_0\``
```

I then use `list` to convert the name list (df_list) to list, as I have been told this is an issue.

```
df_list<- list(df_list)
```

This worked last night, however for some reason after restarting my session today (and updating my packages) it no longer works.

When I do a conditional check of row names

```
dfA[[1]][-1]%>% colnames(.) == df_list[[1]]
```

I get this before applying `list`

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But this after

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I do no know why but df_list[[1]] now returns both list times rather than just list [1]

**before** apply `list`

```
[1] "day"     "10938_0" "12881_0"
```

**after** apply `list`

```
[[1]]
[1] "day"     "10938_0" "12881_0"

[[2]]
[1] "day"     "12881_0" "79916_0"
```

Any suggestions as to why and how to fix it? Alternatively, its only columns which start with numbers that I need to append the prefix too, but I can't see an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the `str_remove` is applied on the entire dataset and according to `?str_remove` the input `string` would be

> string - Input vector. Either a character vector, or something coercible to one

`data.frame/tibble` are not coercible to `vector`

This can be reproduced with a simple example

```
head(iris) %>% 
     str_remove("\\..*")
#[1] "c(5"                 "c(3"                 "c(1"                 "c(0"                 "c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)"
```

instead it should be applied on each column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
purrr::map(df_list, ~ .x %>%
                          rename_all(~ str_remove(.,"ITEM")))
```

Comment: This makes sense and I would select it for the answer, however when I use this code in place of the remove function above I get this: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character". Is this because the list is not actually tables by column names?

Comment: @Comte Is there any list element that is not a data.frame or tibble i.e.  here we assume the list elements are all of data.frame/tibble.  If itis not, then `rename_all` could fail